# Appending 2-D numpy array to txt file

Tags: python, macos, numpy, tensorflow, keras

My program prints a variable `predictions` when executed, which is a 2-D numpy array.  I am attempting to write the output to a text file.  I ensured the shape is 2D by using `predictions.shape` and checked the type to be `<class numpy.ndarray>` by using `type(predictions)`

The error I am receiving is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    predictor()
  File "/Users/owner/Desktop/algo/predict.py", line 146, in predictor
    predictions.savetxt("predictions.txt", "a", delimiter=',', fmt='%d',  header='', footer='')
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'savetxt'
```

This is returned after I call the function in the python module.

Im sure Ive imported numpy correctly, am I using the `savetxt()` function incorrect?

I tried searching on Stack but couldn't find anything, Thank you.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html

Comment: `savetxt` is a numpy function, not an array method.  Review its docs.

Comment: What's the "a" supposed to be doing? Nothing in the docs about that.  `stack` search isn't going to help if you don't follow the docs. No one else will not-follow in the same way and get the same error.

Comment: @hpaulj I am trying to append to the file, sorry youre right I should followed the docs more closely

Comment: It is possible to open a file in append mode, and pass that to `loadtxt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the savetext method is not a method on the array, but in the numpy package. You can use it by calling the method and passing in the array:

```py
numpy.savetxt("predictions.txt", predictions, delimiter=',', fmt='%d',  header='', footer='')
```

or `np.savetext(..)` if you did `import numpy as np`

Comment: Yes thank you that words.  One more question tho, when i `print(predictions)` it returns [[1654.676]]. but in the text file only '1654' appears.  Any idea where the decimals went?  Is that what fmt controls? And I wish to add to the file not to re-write it everytime.  Thank you